# Why calculating variance this way is wrong?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, simulation

I'm conducting a set of computer simulations (of membrane). I sample a property (area, $a$) in the following manner:

$ A = \sum _1^N a \\
 S = \sum _1^N a^2 $

During my data analysis, I calculate the variance:

$\text{Var} = S/N - (A/N)^2$

Now, I know that the variance should be positive but I get negative results. For example:
$ N= 37956, A = 7764029.43233427, S =  1492730484.16737$. In my code, the summation is done by

```
A = A + a  
S = S + a*a
```

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: What are $A$ and $S$ initially?

Comment: @RonGordon 0, naturally. Although there are occasion where I load results from prior simulation. In these occasions, they are values which where generated the same way, starting from 0. I also store N. **Edit:** You might have found the problem though. when I load the number of steps, I load them into the wrong variable. This mean that $N$ is smaller than it should...

Comment: Your formulas look correct. Can you run your code on a small vector of $a$ values for which you know the variance? e.g. the variance of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} is 3.5. Also, what language are you using? Might you be suffering from arithmetic overflow?

Comment: @Gereth, thanks. Knowing that this approach is correct is an advancement. My server doesn't allow me to access now so I'll have to test this later.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is prone to disastrous loss of precision due to subtraction of two almost-equal large numbers, especially if the standard deviation is small relative to the mean.  Alternative computations with better numerical qualities can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance